# Telnet losing connection when key is pressed

Tags: python, server, command-prompt, telnet

I'm currently playing around with programming servers in python for the first time and I am using telnet for my current one. I am using the name testserver.py as my file containing the server's code in Python.

```
python testserver.py
```

I can provide server code if needed but my main issue is stemming from when I input the following text into the command prompt:

```
telnet localhost 8000
```

Where 8000 is an arbitrary number used to represent my port. I then click enter and telnet connects to the host. But as soon as I press a key on the keyboard, the contents of the server, in my case "Hello, World!", are displayed and telnet loses connection. Essentially, my telnet session is ending but I need to keep it open... How can I fix this from happening?

Comment: I think add your server code. Telnet will normally keep connection alive until it's explicitly closed (or network issue). Speak soon!

Comment: how would i go about doing that

Comment: Hey there. Sorry, I mean add the server code to the question please. Also the telnet output. Actually wondering now if this is standard behaviour for telnet. Been a while since used it. Will check it out...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment`telnet` should keep connection alive as long as it's not shutdown. If you use the following server code, you should see the behaviour you desire:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9999))
s.listen(1)

c,remote=s.accept()

while(len(c.recv(4096)) > 0):
    c.send("ok\n".encode())
```

Run the above, with something like `python server.py`, and you should then be able to get something like the following behaviour from telnet, which I was able to verify just now within the `python:3.7.3-stretch` docker image (with telnet added).

```
root@c4a34304039b:/# telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
test
ok
test2
ok
```